# insert a element after the odd elements of a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

plz help I can't insert a element after a odd elements in prolog 
this code is inserting 1 after the even elements

```
add([],[]).
add([H|T],[H|[1|T1]]):-
    0 is H mod 2,
    !,
    add(T,T1).
add([H|T],[H|T1]):-
    add(T,T1).
```

Comment: I don't really get what the problem is. If you wrote the code above, then making it insert something after odd elements, looks like an almost trivial change.

Answer (score -1):

In your code the line:

```
0 is H mod 2
```

is checking for an even element. You could just change this to check for an odd element by changing the 0 to a 1:

```
add([],[]).
add([H|T],[H|[1|T1]]):-
    1 is H mod 2,
    !,
    add(T,T1).
add([H|T],[H|T1]):-
    add(T,T1).
```

Now it'll do like before, but put the 1 in after odd elements.

To make it steadfast, as suggested in the comments, you'll need an additional guard, which also means you can remove the cut.

```
add([],[]).
add([H|T],[H|[1|T1]]):-
    1 is H mod 2,
    add(T,T1).
add([H|T],[H|T1]):-
    0 is H mod 2,
    add(T,T1).
```

Comment: Both `add([3],[3,1]).` and `add([3],[3]).` succeed.

Comment: Indeed it does, and I thought it was odd too. But Amine gave no indication of whether or not that's  the desired behaviour, only that they wanted their code to work on odd elements instead of even.

Comment: But that is **your** error! `add([3], L)` produces only `L = [3,1]` which is the expected answer. A relation should behave like a relation. Your program is not steadfast.

Comment: I gave the answer to the question asked: "how to make *that code* work with odd elements instead of even ones?". How to make *that code* steadfast is a different question. However, it is an important issue, so I've added it to the solution.